# Conditional expectation and Dirac delta function

Tags: local-volatility

In the proof of `Dupire equation` we end up with an identity involving the `Dirac delta function`.

How to prove that
$$\dfrac{E[\sigma_T^2\delta(S_T-K)]}{E[\delta(S_T-K)]}=E[\sigma_T^2|S_T = K].$$

where $\delta(x)$ is the  `Dirac delta function.` $S_T$ is a random variable, and $\sigma_T$ also.

Comment: This is the definition of a conditional expectation. You could write the RHS in integral form and use Bayes to convince yourself of the equality though.

Comment: @Quantuple but it's not the indicator function, the problem is how to deal with the $\delta(0) = \infty$ in the integral.

Comment: You should see this as follows, similarly to $\Bbb{E}\left[ 1\{S_T \geq K\} \right] = P(S_T \geq K)$, $\Bbb{E}\left[ \delta(S_T-K) \right] = p(S_T=K)$, or in integral form $\int_0^\infty \delta(x-K) p(x) dx = p(K)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly abusing notations
\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}\left[ \sigma^2_T \vert S_T = K \right] &= \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sigma^2_T \, p( \sigma^2_T \vert S_T = K) d\sigma^2_T \\
&= \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sigma^2_T \frac{p(\sigma^2_T, S_T=K)}{p(S_T=K)} d\sigma^2_T 
\\
&= \frac{\int_{0}^{+\infty} \sigma^2_T p(\sigma^2_T, S_T=K) d\sigma^2_T }{p(S_T=K)} \\
&= \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sigma^2_T \delta(S_T-K) p(\sigma^2_T, S_T) d\sigma^2_T dS_T }{\int_{0}^{+\infty} \delta(S_T-K) p(S_T) dS_T} \\
&= \frac{\Bbb{E}\left[ \sigma^2 \delta(S_T-K) \right]}{\Bbb{E}\left[ \delta(S_T-K) \right]}
\end{align}